# CDC is enabled but can't see any records in capture tables in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I have enabled CDC but when I tried to query system tables I can't see any records.

```
select * from cdc.ap_vendors_max_CT;
```

It showing no records.

CDC job is running continuously and shows in progress.

Comment: not at all clear ...please go through SO rules

Comment: Check CDC is enabled for table or not. Use: SELECT name, is_cdc_enabled
    FROM sys.databases     and check why and which step job got stuck